# Thread being called multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a code where i am dealing with multiple threads.
One threads wait for the execution of some other threads on which it is dependent.

My run code for thread looks like

```
    public void run() {

    for ( final String name : nameList ) {
      final Thread thread = getThreadByName( name );
      if ( thread != null ) {
          while ( thread.isAlive() ) {
              thread.join();
          }
      }
    }
    //perform action
}
```

There are few other threads waiting for this thread to complete execution in same method like run() by calling join() as shown.

Lets say this thread was dependent on three other threads and it is waiting for them to complete execution in thread.join(). i.e. nameList size is 3 But this thread performs action 3 times also. which is outside for loop.

and i start this thread in another method like

```
    switch ( element.getKey() ) {
        case A
           thread = new Thread( action );
           thread.setName( threadName );
           thread.start();
         break;
```

Due to some reason (Which i am unable to figure out) the thread runs three times.

Does it only run when i call thread.start() method or does it have to do something when other threads are waiting for this thread in thread.join() method ? when this thread is waiting in thread.join(), it should not perform further actions, right ?

UPDATE :

Sorry for unclear question :
There is a print statement right after the run()

run()
//print A
For loop

Then in //perform action there is another print statement
//print B

Both A and B are printed 3 times.
The only thing i think of for the number 3 is because nameList size is 3.

Comment: If you don't get help soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org) or a [minimal example program/mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) where you condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles and runs, has no outside dependencies (such as need to link to a database or images), has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: The question is unclear. Do you claim that the thread's `run` method is executed three times? What proof do you have for that? Did you add a print statement to the start of the `run` method and saw its output three times?

Comment: No need for `isAlive` check at all. `join` returns immediately if the thread is dead. If it didn't you'd be exposed to waiting inside `join` forever.

Comment: As an aside, these kinds of problems can be solved more easily with `Semaphore`s, `CountDownLatch`es and `CyclicBarrier`s. And if you've got a complex system of interlocking threads, it's always a good idea to check whether you really need that many threads in the first place.

Comment: I have to check if the other thread is still running then this thread should keep waiting. Do i need to have the check while (thread.isAlive()) or just if (thread !=null){thread.join()} will serve the purpose ?

Comment: And just for the record: repeating the same question; and giving **no** feedback whatsoever to the person who tried to write up an answer ... well, not exactly helpful. At least from the perspective of that answering person.

Comment: @GhostCat Yes, You were right. I had to make a check when Thread is null.
And also the switch statement was being called from a method twice. It works now. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If things work for you, consider accepting the helpful answer(s) then. Also helps your reputation ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Guessing*: you put that check

```
if ( thread != null ) {
  while ( thread.isAlive() ) {
    thread.join();
  }
}
```

into your code; probably for a reason. In case that call actually returns null, you jump out of your for loop; and then you will run the following action.

So, in case that check really makes sense; you have to prevent leaving that loop level when thread is **null**.

Comment: I don't understand the problem, if the `thread` is null, then there is nothing to wait with that `name`, this loop as no sense after all.

Comment: It depends on the code he is not showing. There could very well be another loop outside ... simply a short in the dark; sometimes they help and get accepted; and sometimes they dont; then they get deleted.

Comment: Yep, I am more concerned about the `switch` or the `getThreadByName` method